# Make AJAX request from CouchDB Show Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, couchdb, couchapp

I'm trying to create a CouchApp somewhat similar to [couchperuser](https://github.com/etrepum/couchperuser) that will create a couch database for each user. My goal is not setup a separate node server as I am looking to achieve a "frontend-only/no-backend" design. My idea was to use a [Show Function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html) that could use the couch admin's username and password to create databases. The problem with this approach is that Show Functions are side effect-free, which means that I cannot use a XMLHttpRequest object or modify a couch doc from within a Show Function. Is there another method available that uses a Show Function, [Update Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) or some other CouchDB construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is impossible.

The only way is to make the XHR request from the browser, after the page is served through the `_show` function. If that suits your needs, then good; if not, then pure CouchApps aren't enough for you and you need a separate backend server.